# How to add client side validation errors in Ember Data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

What is correct way for handling client side validation errors? `DS.Model` class has methods `add` and `clear` that work fine for me, but both are marked as deprecated. What is replacement for those methods?

Comment: To be clear, it's the DS.Errors class where you'll find the deprecations. The model.errors property is an instance of said class. I'm wondering the same thing as I'm using the model.errors object for client side and server side validations. Should I consider using a validation library for client side or is there another mechanism within ember-data that would suffice?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that about correct, but there is a library that can save you some time. If you look at this project you will see how it is used with ember data.

https://github.com/esbanarango/ember-model-validator#user-content-usage-example

In short you have mixin import Validator from '../mixins/model-validator';
 that you import to your model and define validations rules.

People from DockYard also wrote a great add on for EmberObjects which you can check here

https://github.com/DockYard/ember-validations

For me personally this is too much. I prefer to do validation on server side - I am using ActiveModelSerializer and responding to for example 200 or 201 when success and 422 or 401 when unable to process entity or permission denied. This path will use DS.Error object which you can check here...http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Errors.html. The sample easy code would be

```
model.save().then ( (data)=>, (error)=>...
```

Then in your template code you could use following

{{#each model.errors.MYFIELD as |error|}}

I can provide more specific example but your question is generic one.

Hope it helps

Comment: I like how ember data handles the server side validations. It would be nice if you could use the same mechanism for client side but the methods for manipulating the model.errors object have been deprecated. I think the question is how come? and is a replacement provided within ember data or not?

Comment: They marked them as deprecated by mistake: https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/3853#issuecomment-226956166 Those methods are still alive and well.